# Add placeholder to Html.DateTimePickerFor

Tags: html, razor

I have code like that and in TextBoxFor placeholder appears with any problems, but in DateTimePicker placeholder doesn't show.

```
<div>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { autofocus = "autofocus", placeholder = "Is required" })
</div>
<div>
      @Html.DateTimePickerFor(model => model.Date, new {placeholder = "Is required" })
</div>
```

Is it possible to add placeholder to Html.DateTimePickerFor with placeholder attribute or to add this I need to create a new custom DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 0):

For me when I have these kinds of problems I will use the combination of Html and (JavaScript or JQuery) like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { id = "datepicker})
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: "Clear",
        buttonText: "Select Date",
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            inst.dpDiv.find(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

You can read [more](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) about Datepicker.